# Failed to solve the job scheduling wth snakemake on SLURM scheduler

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I'm running a snakemake pipeline on Slurm and am observing a strange error:
[Failed to solve the job scheduling problem with pulp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaWkh.png)

Without SLURM, the pipeline works perfectly fine. However, when I try to run it on SLURM, the job scheduling is strange, the scheduler skips the first Job (Job 0) and directly jumps to Job1. Since Job 0 was missed, there are no input files for Job 1.

Any help/direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I actually managed to solve it. It was a scheduler error on my snakemake version.  I changed scheduler to greedy and it worked on snakemake version 26, else by downgrading to snakemake 5.25.0 and using the default ilp scheduler works as well. Thanks!